# Manage multiple file upload control in one form mvc c#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, file-upload, multiple-instances

I am having one form with multiple file upload control with multiple file selection allowed as shown in below image.

[image]

Now I want data to be submitted in controller as per row in table. One row is one record so need attachment record vise. Tried directed submit but no luck as not having model class. So trying with ajax but not having idea about how to do it. Please help as not having idea about multiple file control.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending via ajax, you need to send it as `FormData` in a `POST` Request.

To read it from your `controller`, you need to use the `Request.Files` in your Action.

You can read every single entry from this property as a `HttpPostedFileBase` instance.

Code example:

```
List<YourFileModel> files = new List<YourFileModel>();
for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
{
    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[i];
    if (file.FileName.Length != 0 && file.ContentLength != 0)
    {
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
        {
            YourFileModel fileModel = new YourFileModel();
            fileModel.FileName = file.FileName;
            fileModel.FileContent = br.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
            files.Add(fileModel);
        }
    }
}
```